Why is the texture mapped properly in the 3D viewport, but not in the UV Editor?
This is how it looks in the 3D viewport, mapped the right way:

Texture of the mesh that is not properly UV mapped in the UV Editor:


It would be helpful if you actually showed us what "right" vs "wrong" looks like. It might also help if you share your Blender project file. Instructions for sharing.

oh well for some reason the website didnt let me post 2 images

Can you point out what exactly about your model is wrong though? We don't even know what you're aiming for so how can we figure out what your issue is.

Are you sure that is the correct UV map for that texture?
